# remove everything after comma in url and redirect in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add some rewrite rules to my htaccess file and I'm having a bit of trouble with a few bits.

I've currently got the following set up (bits are from different sites so I'm sorry if it's not consistent!):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /search\.php\?part=([^&]+)\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ http://test.dev/part/%1? [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^part/(.+)$ /search.php?part=$1 [L]
```

This allows me to go to **test.dev/search.php?part=foo** and it rewrites/redirects the url to **test.dev/part/foo** - this works fine and shows me the correct content.

However, I can also go to **test.dev/search.php?part=foo,bar** and it rewrites/redirects the url to **test.dev/part/foo,bar** - even though this shows up the correct content, this is not what I want the url to look like.

Is there a way to take into account what's in the url after 'part' and if it finds a comma, remove the comma and anything after it?

I'd still need the 'foo' and 'bar' to be read by my code and show the correct content for those two options but for the url to show **test.dev/part/foo** (as foo was the first one in the url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s/+search\.php\?part=([^&,\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /part/%1? [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^part/(.+)$ /search.php?part=$1 [L,NC]
```

**UPDATE:** To capture string after comma into query string

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s/+search\.php\?part=([^&,\s]+)(?:,([^&,\s]+))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /part/%1?q=%2 [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^part/(.+)$ /search.php?part=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for that - I can confirm that **test.dev/search.php?part=foo,bar** has been rewritten to **test.dev/part/foo** (which is what I wanted) but now my code is only looking for a "part" that's "foo" and not "foo,bar" (my code splits the "foo,bar" on the comma and looks for parts that equal "foo" or "bar") - do you know how I can still make the site believe it's to look for "foo" and "bar" but have the url only show "foo" (like the code above does)?

Comment: Once an external redirection happens string after comma is gone. If your code can work with query string then it would be possible to supply that via query string.

Comment: Not to sound dumb but can you give me an example of this so that I can still do what the code above is doing for redirecting and rewriting but also keeping the querystring so I can use it in my code?

Comment: ah, I see what you mean - thank you. I take it that in order for me to have the 'foo,bar' working is that I can either have the comma in the rewritten URL (which was my original code) or I have no commas but need the q= bit at the end (your revised examples)?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I meant.

Comment: In that case, I'm going to mark this answer as correct as I believe it has answered my original question :) thank you for your help!